# Why my fan RPM drops to 0 cycling?

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on a Dell E6430 and I am using the command

```
watch sensors
```

I can notice that, despite the temperature (around 70degrees) the fan is going max speed and after 2-3 seconds dropping to 0.

Sometimes it is stable for some time, but mostly is doing this on/off.

I tried to setup fancontrol but it doesn't seems it changed anything.

I read around forums that someone else had the same problem, blaming the hardware, the bios and so on but no real solutions.

I tried on Windows and is seems I cannot reproduce it there.

My sensors command:

```
dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 2972 RPM
CPU:            +62.0°C  
Ambient:        +49.0°C  
SODIMM:         +45.0°C  
GPU:            +55.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.5°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +65.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +65.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +60.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Comment: Isn't the fan controlled in your BIOS? In my opinon 70 degrees is quite hot. Perhaps it is an idea to look at and clean your fan? Both the output as well as cleaning the fan blades with a brush.

Comment: I already tried to clean with compressed air, not that much dust. In my opinion also 70 is a bit too high since it reaches it when in idle.

Right now it's around 60, that seems a threshold, it spins faster when 61 and then drops to 0, so I am thinking it is some wrong setting somewhere

Comment: I think you better read the manual of the machine to see if that has more info. Otherwise I have no other suggestions.

Comment: @WillemK 70C isn't *that* bad. My E6530 reaches 102C when  rendering... I probably should replace the thermal compound...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be solved with something unexpected:

```
sudo service i8kmon stop
```

Or better (should persist after reboot)

```
sudo systemctl disable i8kmon.service
```

Probably the configuration is wrong or I don't know, but when I turned it off the fan started to behave normally, no more on/off cycles

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to configure the fans? I've had good results with by installing `i8kutils` and `lm-sensors`, then adding the following configuration file to `/etc/i8kmon.conf`:

```
# Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon)      0

# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto)        1

# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 1

# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 20

# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  40  -1  40}
set config(1)   {{-1 1}  30  60  30  60}
set config(2)   {{-1 2}  53  128  53  128}

# For computer with 2 fans, use a variant of this instead:
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# set config(0) {{-1 0}  -1  52  -1  65}
# set config(1) {{-1 1}  41  66  55  75}
# set config(2) {{-1 1}  55  80  65  85}
# set config(3) {{-1 2}  70 128  75 128}

# end of file
```

Then you can run `/usr/bin/i8kmon -d -a` to start controlling the fans based on the temperature. It'll stop running on reboot, so I'd suggest adding it to your startup programs.

This has worked for me, but it's possible that you're also experiencing a hardware problem ie. a failing fan so YMMV.

Comment: Just make sure you test test it before enabling it on boot. Miss-configuring could make it worse

Comment: I used PWMConfig, I will give it a try with your suggestion as well. I tried windows for some time and it never happened, the temperatures are the same but the fan doesn't do those on/off cycles.Unfortunately I cannot read the fan speed on windows for some reason. But this means it is some sw problem.

Comment: As @wilf said, don't forget to test the config before enabling it on boot, but also you may have to fiddle with the temperature thresholds to get it just right for your system. It works for me, but you may need it to be a little different.

Comment: It seems it works, the fan now are 3000+RPM when the temperature is above 70, no more drops to 0. I also configured fancontrol so I cannot be sure 100% this solved it, but it should.

Comment: Well, doesn't work anymore :-(